# SSIS to insert non-matching data on non-linked server

Tags: ssis

This is regarding SQL Server 2008 R2 and SSIS.

I need to update dozens of history tables on one server with new data from production tables on another server.

The two servers are not, and will not be, linked.

Some of the history tables have 100's of millions of rows and some of the production tables have dozens of millions of rows.

I currently have a process in place for each table that uses the following data flow components:

1. OLEDB Source task to pull the appropriate production data.
2. Lookup task to check if the production data's key already exists in the history table and using the "Redirect to error output" -
3. Transfer the missing data to the OLEDB Destination history table.

The process is too slow for the large tables.  There has to be a better way.  Can someone help?

I know if the servers were linked a single set based query could accomplish the task easily and efficiently, but the servers are not linked.

Comment: In your OLEDB source, are you using the _SQL Command_ for the data access mode? A common performance tip is to use _SQL Command_ and write a select statement getting **only** the columns you need.

Answer (score 1):

Segment your problem into smaller problems. That's the only way you're going to solve this.

Let's examine the problems.

1. You're inserting and/or updating existing data. At a database level, rows are packed into pages. Rarely is it an exact fit and there's usually some amount of free space left in a page. When you update a row, pretend the Name field went from "bob" to "Robert Michael Stuckenschneider III". That row needs more room to live and while there's *some* room left on the page, there's not enough. Other rows might get shuffled down to the next page just to give this one some elbow room. That's going to cause lots of disk activity. Yes, it's inevitable given that you are adding more data but it's important to understand *how* your data is going to grow and ensure your database itself is ready for that growth. Maybe, you have some non-clustered indexes on a target table. Disabling/dropping them should improve insert/update performance. If you still have your database and log set to grow at 10% or 1MB or whatever the default values are, the storage engine is going to spend all of its time trying to grow files and won't have time to actually write data. Take away: ensure your system is poised to receive lots of data. Work with your DBA, LAN and SAN team(s)
2. You have tens of millions of rows in your OLTP system and hundreds of millions in your archive system. Starting with the OLTP data, you need to identify what does not exist in your historical system. Given your data volumes, I would plan for this package to have a hiccup in processing and needs to be "restartable." I would have a package that has a data flow with only the business keys selected from the OLTP that are used to make a match against the target table. Write those keys into a table that lives on the OLTP server (ToBeTransfered). Have a second package that uses a subset of those keys (N rows) joined back to the original table as the Source. It's wired directly to the Destination so no lookup required. That fat data row flows on over the network only one time. Then have an Execute SQL Task go in and delete the batch you just sent to the Archive server. This batching method can allow you to run the second package on multiple servers. The SSIS team describes it better in their paper: [We loaded 1TB in 30 minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
3. Ensure the Lookup is a Query of the form `SELECT key1, key2 FROM MyTable` Better yet, can you provide a filter to the lookup? `WHERE ProcessingYear = 2013` as there's no need to waste cache on 2012 if the OLTP only contains 2013 data.
4. You might need to modify your [PacketSize](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/top10lists/archive/2008/10/01/top-10-sql-server-integration-services-best-practices.aspx) on your Connection Manager and have a network person set up Jumbo frames.
5. Look at your queries. Are you getting good plans? Are your tables over-indexed? Remember, each index is going to result in an increase in the number of writes performed. If you can dump them and recreate after the processing is completed, you'll think your SAN admins bought you some FusionIO drives. I know I did when I dropped 14 NC indexes from a billion row table that only had 10 total columns.

If you're still having performance issues, establish a theoretical baseline (under ideal conditions that will never occur in the real world, I can push 1GB from A to B in N units of time) and work your way from there to what your actual is. You must have a limiting factor (IO, CPU, Memory or Network). Find the culprit and throw more money at it or restructure the solution until it's no longer the lagging metric.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Incremental bulk import of appropriate proudction data to new server.
 Ref: Importing Data from a Single Client (or Stream) into a Non-Empty Table
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177445(v=sql.105).aspx

Step 2. Use Merge Statement to identify new/existing records and operate on them.

I realize that it will take a significant amount of disk space on the new server, but the process would run faster.